# Laravel: The GET method is not supported for route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel-10

I got a weird problem and I couldn't find a similar case.

This is the error I get:

```
The GET method is not supported for route api/event/2/updatePoll/1. Supported methods: POST.
```

And when I scroll down on the Laravel Error Page, it shows the cUrl as a GET

The "weird" thing about it, I only get that error when my controller method looks like this

```
public function addVote(Request $request, string $id, string $pollId)
{
    $poll = Poll::find($pollId)->pollOptions();
    var_export($poll);
}
```

or alternativly

```
$poll = Poll::with(['pollOptions.pollOptionVotes'])->find($pollId);
```

When I do not query the pollOptions, the request is valid

This is the call in api.php

```
Route::post('/event/{id}/updatePoll/{pollId}', [EventController::class, 'addVote']);
```

And this is the Ajax call from my VUE3 App.

```
await apiClient().post(
        `/event/${event.value!.id}/updatePoll/${pollId}`,
        value
    )
```

I already tried

```
php artisan optimize 
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:cache
```

Anyone got any idea? Why is "further" querying a problem?